# RegExp not working as expected while removing some string

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I am extracting some data from a some websites and would like to remove some unnecessarily text from it.

So I did some parsers that can control the parsed content before presenting it to the users.

Here is my test code that I did.

```js
// tried using this but it strill did not work 
function escapeRegex(string) {
return string.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
}

var div = document.getElementById("content");
var txArray = ["If you find any errors ( broken links, non-standard content, etc.. ), Please let us know < report chapter > so we can fix it as soon as possible.", "KobatoChanDaiSuki"]
txArray.forEach(x => {
  var reg = new RegExp(escapeRegex(x), "gi");
  div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.replace(reg, "");
});
```

```html
<div id="content">
Hyung : Big/older brother. Kind of an equivalent to the japanese “onii-san” but only used between male (male to male).
Translator :Pumba
TL Check : KobatoChanDaiSuki
 If you find any errors ( broken links, non-standard content, etc.. ), Please let us know < report chapter > so we can fix it as soon as possible.
</div>
```

Se above it is not removing all the contents, Why is that ?

maybe I need to break the long string and then try to clean it, I really do not know? What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `(`, `)`, and `.` have special meanings in JavaScript regular expressions.  An additional problem is that `<` and `>` are written as `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively in `innerHTML`.  `innerText` avoids this problem. (I figured this out by adding `console.log(div.innerHTML)` to look at the contents; see the snippet below.)

Try this:

```js
var txArray = ["If you find any errors \\( broken links, non-standard content, etc\\.\\. \\), Please let us know < report chapter > so we can fix it as soon as possible\\.", "KobatoChanDaiSuki"]
txArray.forEach(x => {
  var reg = new RegExp(x, "gi");
  div.innerText = div.innerText.replace(reg, "");
});
```

Or you can write code to [escape your regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/7797661), as in the following:

```js
var reg = new RegExp(x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), "gi");
```

```js
var div = document.getElementById("content");
var txArray = ["If you find any errors \\( broken links, non-standard content, etc\\.\\. \\), Please let us know < report chapter > so we can fix it as soon as possible\\.", "KobatoChanDaiSuki"];

txArray.forEach(x => {
  var reg = new RegExp(x, "gi");
  console.log(div.innerHTML);
  div.innerText = div.innerText.replace(reg, "");
});
```

```html
<div id="content">
Hyung : Big/older brother. Kind of an equivalent to the japanese “onii-san” but only used between male (male to male).
Translator :Pumba
TL Check : KobatoChanDaiSuki
 If you find any errors ( broken links, non-standard content, etc.. ), Please let us know < report chapter > so we can fix it as soon as possible.
</div>
```

Comment: No working, I tried what you wrote and its not working. Please try to create a simple runnable code here on stackoverflow.

Comment: See above I updated the code and did as you said and still not working

Comment: Ah, < and > are causing trouble too. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I do not want to write `\\` manually, could you fix  the `escapeRegex` function I wrote instead so i could replace those unwanted char in txArray

Comment: That code should work if you switch from `innerHTML` to `innerText`.